# How to align content in bootstrap div so that it touches the margin of the parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin:0;">
                <article>
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                      <div class="content">
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"><small> 1 June</small></i> &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-clock-o"><small> 11:45 PM</small></i></p>
                        <p>For many individuals and businesses developing a strong social media presence is a cornerstone of their digital strategy, so prioritising social media.... <a href=""><font color="#88c78a">Read More</font></a></p>
                        <div class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <small> 400 Views</small></div>
                        <div class="pull-left" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <small> 400 Likes</small></div>
                      </div>
                </article>
            </div>


    <!-- End Row -->
    </div>

<!-- End Container -->
</div>
```

My div currently looks like this:http://s13.postimg.org/fdis1mxyv/div.png

If you go through the image then you will see that there is some space from left and right green margin. I want that space to go away.

Which attribute of div will help do this thing?

Comment: remove margin:0; and write padding:0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute in the css that makes that it writes the content of the child objects is the attribute called "padding". There is 5 types of different paddings :

- padding=*X*; Makes the content to be wrote with a margin at every side
- padding-top:*X*; Makes the content to be wrote with a margin from the top
- padding-left:*X*; Makes the content to be wrote with a margin from the left side
- padding-right:*X*; Makes the content to be wrote with a margin from the right side
- padding-bottom:*X*; Makes the content to be wrtoe with a margin from the bottom

And then, you can play with these in CSS by specifying only the ones that you want (the number *X* is either in px or in %. e.g.: padding-top:10px;)
So for your  you have to search the child parent class that contains the childs you want to be aligned to the div, and you change the value :

```
.parent
{
  padding:*X*px;
  //or padding-top, padding-left, padding-right, padding-bottom, in fonction of wich one you want
}
```

Here is a snippet to show you an example :

```css
.parent_no_padding
{
  padding:0px;
}
.child_no_padding
{
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}
.parent_with_padding
{
  padding:20px;
}
.child_with_padding
{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1"><tr><td>
<!-- Only for the look -->
  
<div class="parent_no_padding">
  <h3>Title here</h3>
    <div class="child_no_padding">
      <p>Content of the child</p>
      Write a little sentence here to make some content (without padding)
    </div>
</div>
  
<br/></td></tr><tr><td>
  
<div class="parent_with_padding">
  <h3>Title here agagin</h3>
    <div class="child_with_padding">
      <p>Content of the child</p>
      Write a second little sentence (with padding)
    </div>
</div>
  
<br/></td></tr><tr><td>
  
<div class="parent_with_padding">
  <h3>Title here over and over</h3>
    <div class="child_no_padding">
      <p>Content of the child</p>
      Write a last little sentence (parent with padding but child without padding)
    </div>
  
</div></td></tr></table>
```

Hope this helps ! (don't forget to check an answer if it's right, to help other people to see what works)